# Help with phrasing of an aspect in Dresden Files

Tags: dresden-files

I'm trying to come up with an aspect for Dresden files, and I know what I want it to be, but I'm having trouble fitting all the connotations into a simple phrase.

My character helps people allot, and makes a good number of sacrifices, like giving a good amount of his income to charity, to do it.  I want an aspect to cover this.  However, he also is very reason and logic focused, and believes that charity should be thought through.  He believes that since he only has so many resources to give he needs to ensure he invests what he has efficiently.  Because of this he tends to excessively analyze how to optimize his charity, and generally thinks most people aren't efficient in their charitable intentions.

I want this distinction to be very clear in the aspect, because it's a key part of his character.  To give an example imagine a compel where a friend who's known to be bad with repaying loans shows up and asks my character to loan him enough to fix his broken car.  Despite his focus on helping, my character would not make the loan.  His reasoning being  that he wants to donate the money to a charity that on average could save 1-2 lives for the expense of fixing the friends car, which is a more optimal use of it.

So these two details, giving allot for others, and being picky about optimizing it, must be in the aspect; however, I have other things I would like to 'fit in' if I can.

1. While mostly logical he sometimes struggles with a strong compassion when it comes to letting someone suffer because it's 'optimal'.  Particularly when making decisions quickly or in the heat of the moment he may take risks that are 'sub-optimal' because he didn't have time to think it over and made a more emotional decision (so he can still be compelled to do something more dramatic in the heat of the moment).  In general when making 'sub-optimal' decisions it's because he takes risks/sacrifices to himself when he shouldn't for the sake of others.
2. I really like the idea of others not always 'getting' his reasoning.  Like the example above where he may have alienated his friend by giving money to some unknown charity rather then helping the friend, it's 'optimal' but still could anger the friend.  Others may simply fail to understand his full logic, he could go into long tangents about game theory and risk-reward analysis but most can't follow it all so he doesn't bother.
3. It would be nice if it was written in such a way that I could use the aspect to grant *others* a bonus, as he's a 'support character' at heart, and his combat style is mostly supporting others.  This is least important because I can build his support nature via stunts or other aspects.

Can anyone help suggest a good aspect for all this?

Some options that came close, but didn't quite work, usually by failing to express his underlying compassion and occasional struggle to stick to allow harm to others to occur even when 'optimal':

```
"The needs of the many outweighs the needs of the one" 
"Optimized sacrifice"
```

Comment: There are some kinds of questions that don't work in the Stack Exchange Q&A format, and asking for help with ideas is one of them. [Your question might be better suited to a chat room or a traditional forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), as you'll get more helpful feedback on a site intended for open-ended discussion.